# Mockery not able to register mocks

Tags: node.js, mockery

I was using mockery.enable({useCleanCache: true}) option and it was working fine but when I upgraded the node version it started failing. It is no longer picking the mocks registered by mockery. I tried using mockery.registerMock but still have the UT hitting actual module instead of mock.
Anyone facing similar issues ?